# Taylor and Big-O

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

**Given:**

$P_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial for $f(x)$ at $x=a$.

$Q_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$. Where $f(x)=Q_n(x)+O(x-a)^{n+1}$ as $x \to a$

**Now my calculus-book states:**

> $R_n(x)=Q_n(x)-P_n(x)=O((x-a)^{n+1})$ as $x\to a$
>
> By replacing $x$ with $a+(x-a)$ and expanding powers we can write
>   $R_n(x)$ in the form $R_n(x)=c_0+c_1(x-a)+c_2(x-a)^2+...+c_n(x-a)^n$.

**QUESTION:**

- Is it correct to say that the order of both $Q_n(x)$ and $P_n(x)$ equals $O((x-a)^n)$ as $x \to a$?
- Then why is the order of $R_n(x)=Q_n(x)-P_n(x)=O((x-a)^{n+1})$ as $x\to a$?
- Doesn't the last statement in my calculusbook imply that $R_n(x)=O((x-a)^n)$ as $x \to a$?

**Context of the question**
[image]

---

**EDIT**

After some thought I think my confusion came from the fact that $O$ is different when $x \to a$ as opposed to $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that the order of both $Q_n(x)$ and $P_n(x)$
>   equals $O((x-a)^n)$ as $x \to a$?

No, the order of both equals $O(1)$ as $x\to a$ since near $a$ that is the dominant degree.

> Then why is the order of $R_n(x)=Q_n(x)-P_n(x)=O((x-a)^{n+1})$ as
>   $x\to a$?

Because if you substract these two equations:
$$f(x)=P_n(x)+O((x-a)^{n+1})$$
$$f(x)=Q_n(x)+O((x-a)^{n+1})$$
You'll get:
$$0=P_n(x)-Q_n(x)+O((x-a)^{n+1})$$
$$Q_n(x)-P_n(x)=O((x-a)^{n+1})$$

> Doesn't the last statement in my calculusbook imply that
>   $R_n(x)=O((x-a)^n)$ as $x \to a$?

No, the order of $R_n(x)=c_0+c_1(x-a)+c_2(x-a)^2+...+c_n(x-a)^n$ equals $O(1)$ as $x\to a$

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that
$$
R_n(a+h)=c_0+c_1h+...+c_nh^n
$$
the degree is bound by $n$ since both $P_n$ and $Q_n$ have degree $n$.

In the end the conclusion should be $R_n=0$ since all the $c_k=0$. If not, then for the smallest $k$ with $c_k\ne 0$ you would get $R_n(x)=O((x-a)^k)$ for some $k\le n$ contradicting the assumptions.